# SQL injections (java)

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to figure out a way to see if the sql injection is correct based on the user input and if so, delete that row. 
For instance the user enters 123 for an idNumber, if that number exits, the the sql statement "select * from student where idNumber = " + idNumber + ";" would be correct.
When it is verified that it is correct, I would then use another statement to delete the query.
My main issue is figuring out how to verify it is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Trying to see if the sql injection is correct"*? [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) of user-supplied values is never correct, unless you like your data stolen and/or deleted by malicious hackers. Use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Agree with @Andreas comments. More over why do you want to check the correctness of the used input using sql injection? Use PreparedStatement to bind the user ID to the sql and then check if the query returns a row. If yes, then run the delete statement. Avoid SQL Injection for prod use.

Comment: If by *"delete the query"* you actually mean "delete the student", why not just run the `delete` statement, and see if anything got deleted? No need to waste time on a `select` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void CheckStudent(Connection con, String idNumber) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "select * from student where idNumber = " + idNumber + ";"
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
      if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) { 
       //Here is where you do the check   
            System.out.println("No data"); 
      } 
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```